# Calculating sum of array objects in javascript , TypeError: parseInt(...).reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array of objects with numbers but there type is string , I want to sum them all.

[image]

I'm doing this way as of previous answers on stack-overflow suggested.

```
// Here the data has an array of goods which contains
// amount objects and i want to calculate to sum of amount objects
Total Invoice Price:
{data.goods
   ? data.goods.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
     <div>{parseInt(item.amount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}</div>
       </div >
       ))
     : null}
```

But im getting error `TypeError: parseInt(...).reduce is not a function` , How to fix this ?

Comment: `reduce` is an array method. `parseInt(good.amount)` doesn't return an array.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you should share the structure of amount. It needs conversion to array

Comment: could you share "goods" array

Comment: the how we can fix this to calculate the sum of all `amount ` objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reduce` is an array method. So: instead of *mapping* over the data, call a function within your JSX that returns the sum of the `amount` values of each object in the array.

Note: if your amount values are strings coerce them to numbers first (`Number(good.amount)`).

```js
function Example({ data }) {

  function getTotal(data) {
    return data.goods.reduce((acc, good) => {
      return acc + Number(good.amount);
    }, 0);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Total</h4>
      <p>{getTotal(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );

}

const data = { goods: [{ amount: '1' }, { amount: '5' }, { amount: '13' }] };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
goods = [{
    amount: "11"
  },
  {
    amount: "11"
  },
  {
    amount: "11"
  },
]

let sum = goods.reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b.amount), 0)

console.log(sum)
```